# What application / language to make a database for booking accomodation?

Tags: php, database, forms

Hey guys I'm going to have a lot of free time once my exams are out of the way (Second year comp sci). I want to learn php, and I have a project to work on - making a form for a website to book a room at a backpackers. For this to work properly I will need to store some infortmation regarding how many beds are left for that night in a database.

1. I will use PHP and HTML for the form - What do I use to make a database of available rooms.
2. How will I update this database from outside of the website (e.g. when A client books in over the phone).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q#1:
Many people use phpmyadmin (which also comes packed in wamp if you're on Windows). But if you are on windows I would recommend a software named Navicat. That's the only thing we use at the office. If you're on linux I recommend learning commandlines. If you don't want to learn that you can of course set up phpmyadmin.

Q#2:
Then you should have some sort of backend registering system so that the person who answers the call can do the registration.

Another option to Q#2 would be that a person answers the call, goes to the backend, fills out the persons name and email, and a confirmation email containing a "complete the form" link is sent to the caller, letting caller fill out the rest of the info.

Comment: I've googled the subject and a lot of people seem to reccomend mysql, what is the difference with this?

Comment: Aha. Now I get it :) I thought you had already decided on the type of database (thought you already had selected mysql), and that you was asking what you could use to control the database. My bad! Yeah you should absolutely use MySQL, and when you start developing you should avoid all mysql_* functions and at least user mysqli, but most preffered would be PDO. Just thought I'd mention that as well, so that you can "get it right" from the beginning (in case you didn't allready know of course)